# Is it best practice to place Java project directly under the Source Code Repository

Tags: java, git

Any pros and cons or creating additional folders under a repository ?

The example scenario below elaborates the question further:-

e.g. Say we are using Git as an SCM.

**Option 1**

```
myrepository/my-favorite-maven-project-1
                    |____pom.xml

            /my-favorite-maven-project-2
                    |____pom.xml
```

**Option 2**

```
myrepository/SomeFolder1/my-favorite-maven-project-1
                    |____pom.xml

            /SomeFolder1/SomeFolder2/my-favorite-maven-project-2
                    |____pom.xml
```

I would like to get pros and cons with the Option 1 and Option 2.

Comment: It doesn't matter much as long as your projects can find each other if needed (so you do not have to install project 1 before changes is picked up by project 2)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen How do you checkout just the `project-1` if you are not workinh on `project-2` without getting into `git submodule` ?

Comment: You can't.  Based on my personal experiences, have a single repo with multiple maven modules for each project works the best.  In other words, a single "git clone" gives you everything for this project, and nothing for other projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting multiple maven projects under a single git repository makes sense if both of the projects are in fact modules of each other and they are released/branched at the same time.

It's a mistake if you're moving from SVN where you've had a single large SVN repo and lots of projects next to each other though. The reason is, SVN branches/tags work at the folder level, but in Git they work at the repository level. So if you're branching/releasing `project-1` and `project-2` separately, they should be in separate Git repositories.

The corollary is that there's very little point in having a top level folder `SomeFolder1` because there's almost no reason you'd ever have a `SomeFolder2`.